# Cocos2d V3 How change z order of child? reorderChild is not available in V3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, children, ccnode

Cocos2D V3 does not contain CCNode reorderChild:z:
How can I change the z order of a CCNode in V3?
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Like you always could and should have, by using the [`zOrder`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCNode.html#//api/name/zOrder) property.

You can also `#import "CCNode_Private.h"` to gain access to that method. But know that behind the scenes changing `zOrder` does nothing but call `reorderChild:z:` on your behalf anyway.